# Connection to Google IoT with Hive MQTT client instead of Paho

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, google-cloud-iot, hivemq

I have working code similar to [this](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#configuring_mqtt_clients) connecting to google IoT with the paho client.

Since I am in a spring boot reactive application, I would like to use [Hive MQTT Client](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-mqtt-client), but I can't find the right setup, I keep having the following error message  :

```
com.hivemq.client.mqtt.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Server closed connection without DISCONNECT.
```

The current code I use :

```
    hiveClient = MqttClient.builder()
            .identifier(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .serverHost("mqtt.googleapis.com")
            .serverPort(443)
            .useMqttVersion3()
            .sslWithDefaultConfig()
            .simpleAuth(
                    Mqtt3SimpleAuth.builder()
                            .username("unused")
                            .password(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode("// a token string generation that works fine with palo"))
                            .build()
            )
            .build()
            .toBlocking();
    hiveClient.connect(); // Error
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the identifier (client ID) should be set to something other than a UUID. The [documentation indicates the client ID](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge) should be formed as the following path:

```
projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/registries/REGISTRY_ID/devices/DEVICE_ID
```

Note that all of [the requirements for the Google Cloud IoT Core MQTT device bridge](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/protocols) are strict, so also verify that Hive is configured as follows:

- Mqtt 3.1.1
- TLS 1.2
- Publish to `/devices/DEVICE_ID/events` or `/devices/DEVICE_ID/state`
- Subscribe to `/devices/DEVICE_ID/config` or `/devices/DEVICE_ID/commands/#`
- QoS 0 or 1

Note that if you do not adhere to the requirements, your device gets disconnected. Additional information on the disconnect reason may be available in the logging for your registry visible on the [Cloud Console for IoT](https://console.cloud.google.com/iot).